# Multiple jQuery carousels on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.barrelny.com/blog/building-a-jquery-slideshow-plugin-from-scratch/) to create a carousel and so far it's working well enough, but I'm a beginner and I need to have multiple instances of this carousel running on a single page. The carousels show up and actually work, however they animate at the same time on the set delay, and when clicking the next/prev buttons or the paging dots. I need them to run independently of each other. I would really appreciate any advice.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: It's basically [this](http://codepen.io/barrel/pres/oBefw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seperate your carousels with individual class. change a bit code at event function like this

```
Zippy.prototype.events = function(){
    this.$el
        .on('click',this.settings.arrowRight,{direction:'right'},this.changeSlide)
        .on('click',this.settings.arrowLeft,{direction:'left'},this.changeSlide)
        .on('click','.indicators li',this.changeSlide);
};
```

> Demo: http://codepen.io/barrel/pres/oBefw

Comment: Thanks, that works! I had a feeling it was going to be something embarrassingly simple.

Answer (score 0):

possibly click events are working with classes not with ids.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, you have something like this:

```
var args = {
    arrowRight : '.arrow-right', //A jQuery reference to the right arrow
    arrowLeft : '.arrow-left', //A jQuery reference to the left arrow
    speed : 1000, //The speed of the animation (milliseconds)
    slideDuration : 4000 //The amount of time between animations (milliseconds)
};

$('.carousel').Zippy(args);
```

here use args1, args2, args3 etc for each of the slider and use different class for carousel (e.g. carousel1, carousel2, carousel3 etc.)

then change slideDuration speed etc. So the first slider will be

```
var args1 = {
    arrowRight : '.arrow-right', //A jQuery reference to the right arrow
    arrowLeft : '.arrow-left', //A jQuery reference to the left arrow
    speed : 1000, //The speed of the animation (milliseconds)
    slideDuration : 4000 //The amount of time between animations (milliseconds)
};

$('.carousel1').Zippy(args1);
```

the second slider will be

```
var args2 = {
    arrowRight : '.arrow-right', //A jQuery reference to the right arrow
    arrowLeft : '.arrow-left', //A jQuery reference to the left arrow
    speed : 2000, //The speed of the animation (milliseconds)
    slideDuration : 5000 //The amount of time between animations (milliseconds)
};

$('.carousel2').Zippy(args2);
```